# Make websocket receive data readable - nodejs

Tags: node.js, websocket, ws

i just started to learn coding today and messing around with websockets.

I'm using the npm package ws to connect to a websocket server and i'm trying to work out what the data is i'm receiving.

I thought i was going to receive a json because i'm sending a json to the websocket server but it looks nothing like a json.

So my question is could someone maybe tell me what the data is i'm receiving and is there anyway i can make it readable?

The data i'm receiving:

```
{
  [Uint8Contents]: <b0 01 00 a1 71 01 00 00 01 00 00 01 32 18 a0 43 8c 8c 9d c2 df 18 12 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>,
  byteLength: 32
}
```

Not sure if this helps with my question  but here is my function i'm using to connect to websocket:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const connect = (endpoint) => {
  try {
    let options = {
      headers: {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3419.0 Safari/537.36"
      }
    };

    let client = new WebSocket(endpoint, options);

    client.onopen = () => {
      console.log("websocket open");
      client.send("42" + JSON.stringify(["getRooms", false]));
    };

    client.onmessage = (event) => {
      console.log("websocket message:", event.data);
    };

    client.onclose = (reason) => {
      console.log("websocket close:", reason.code);
    };

    client.onerror = (error) => {
      console.log("websocket error:", error.message);
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("connect error:", error.message);
  }
};

connect("ws://ServerHere:PortHere");
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually receive a `Buffer` object on the server. Call `.toString()` on the received data and it will be readable text. A `Buffer` is binary data. That's the way the data is sent over the `socket`.

Maybe you want to have a look at [socket.io](https://socket.io/) package which makes using sockets easier in the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for the info i really appreciate it. And i thought you can't use socket.io to connect to a websocket from what i read somewhere?

Comment: Yes. You would have to use `socket.io` on `client-` and `serverside`.